# Remove a specific word from a div in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

checked input

```
<input id="add_stop" name="attach_img" type="checkbox" class="required custom-control-input">
```

Here is my div

```
<div class="emojionearea-editor">
 Hello World.  STOP to opt out 
</div>
```

I want to remove just `STOP to opt out` if it exists in the inner HTML of div.

here is my jquery code

```
$('#add_stop').change(function (event) {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        if ($('.emojionearea-editor').html().indexOf("STOP to opt out") != -1) {

        } else {
            $('.emojionearea-editor').append('STOP to opt out ');
        }


    } else {
        var name = $('.emojionearea-editor').html();

        /* remove code should be here.... */

        alert(name);
    }
});
```

Here I want to add when checked. I append the text when it not exist. Now I want to remove text if it exists. Now my question is **How can I remove the existing text from inner Html??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
$('#add_stop').change(function (event) {
var keyword = 'STOP to opt out';
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        if ($('.emojionearea-editor').html().indexOf(keyword) != -1) {

        } else {
            $('.emojionearea-editor').append(keyword);
        }

    } else {
        var name = $('.emojionearea-editor').text().replace(keyword,"");
        alert(name);
    }
});
```

I've made the words you want to replace into a variable. That way when you chance the text in the variable it will apply to every place where it's used.

Please note that you should use `.text()` and not `.html()` since the `.html()` will include all html code in that object.

**Demo**

```js
$('#add_stop').change(function (event) {
var keyword = 'STOP to opt out';
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        if ($('.emojionearea-editor').html().indexOf(keyword) != -1) {

        } else {
            $('.emojionearea-editor').append(keyword);
        }

    } else {
        var name = $('.emojionearea-editor').text().replace(keyword,"");
        alert(name);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="add_stop" name="attach_img" type="checkbox" class="required custom-control-input">


<div class="emojionearea-editor">
 Hello World.  STOP to opt out 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

html() function takes one parameter to set inner Html of the DOM.
So like this:

```
var text = $('.emojionearea-editor').html();
text = text.replace("STOP to opt out", "");
$('.emojionearea-editor').html(text);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var name = $('.emojionearea-editor').html().replace("STOP to opt out", "");

$('.emojionearea-editor').html(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed your JQuery code a bit

```
$("#add_stop").change(function() {
  if(this.checked){
    if(!$(".emojionearea-editor").html().includes("STOP to opt out ")){
      $(".emojionearea-editor").append("STOP to opt out ")
    }
  }else{
        var name = $('.emojionearea-editor').text();

        $('.emojionearea-editor').text(name.replace("STOP to opt out ", ""))

        alert(name);
  }
})
```

This should allow you to add and remove the "STOP to opt out"

[Here's a codepen with it working](https://codepen.io/dosmond/pen/XWXjweM)